# Trying to change Python code from e-paper display to drive mini PiTFT instead

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I'm working on this [ISS Tracker project](https://github.com/protostax/ProtoStax_ISS_Tracker), but instead of using the e-Paper display, I want to use the [240x135 Mini PiTFT display](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-mini-pitft-135x240-color-tft-add-on-for-raspberry-pi/overview) instead. I've been trying to rewrite the Python code to accomplish this, as the rendering code is the same, but I cannot get it to output to the new display correctly. I'm *extremely* noobish when it comes to Python code, so any help you could offer would be most appreciated. The source code is available at the above ISS Tracker link, and my altered code is below:

```
#   International Space Station Tracker.
#   using Raspberry Pi B+, Waveshare ePaper Display and ProtoStax enclosure
#   --> https://www.waveshare.com/product/modules/oleds-lcds/e-paper/2.7inch-e-paper-hat-b.htm
#   --> https://www.protostax.com/products/protostax-for-raspberry-pi-b
#
#   It displays the current location of the ISS and also its tracked trajectory. The
#   current location is shown by the ISS icon, and the trajectory by small circles.
#   15 minute markers are shown as small rectangles.
#
#   ISS Current Location is obtained using Open Notify ISS Current Location API
#   http://open-notify.org/Open-Notify-API/ISS-Location-Now/
#
#   Written by Sridhar Rajagopal for ProtoStax.
#   BSD license. All text above must be included in any redistribution
# *


import sys
sys.path.append(r'lib')

if sys.version_info[0] < 3:
    raise Exception("Must be using Python 3")

from enum import Enum
import signal
import board
import digitalio
import adafruit_rgb_display.st7789 as st7789
import epd2in7b
import epdconfig

from PIL import Image,  ImageDraw,  ImageFont, ImageOps
from datetime import datetime
from time import time, sleep

import requests

# START mini pitft code

# Configuration for CS and DC pins (these are FeatherWing defaults on M0/M4):
cs_pin = digitalio.DigitalInOut(board.CE0)
dc_pin = digitalio.DigitalInOut(board.D25)
reset_pin = None
 
# Config for display baudrate (default max is 24mhz):
BAUDRATE = 64000000
 
# Setup SPI bus using hardware SPI:
spi = board.SPI()

# Create the ST7789 display:
disp = st7789.ST7789(
    spi,
    cs=cs_pin,
    dc=dc_pin,
    rst=reset_pin,
    baudrate=BAUDRATE,
    width=135,
    height=240,
    x_offset=53,
    y_offset=40,
)
 
# Create blank image for drawing.
# Make sure to create image with mode 'RGB' for full color.
height = disp.width  # we swap height/width to rotate it to landscape!
width = disp.height
image = Image.new("RGB", (width, height))
rotation = 90
 
# Get drawing object to draw on image.
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)
 
# Draw a black filled box to clear the image.
draw.rectangle((0, 0, width, height), outline=0, fill=(0, 0, 0))
disp.image(image, rotation)

# Draw some shapes.
# First define some constants to allow easy resizing of shapes.
padding = -2
top = padding
bottom = height - padding

# Move left to right keeping track of the current x position for drawing shapes.
x = 0

# Turn on the backlight
backlight = digitalio.DigitalInOut(board.D22)
backlight.switch_to_output()
backlight.value = True

# END mini pitft code


# Update Interval for fetching positions
DATA_INTERVAL = 30 #seconds
# Update interval for the display
DISPLAY_REFRESH_INTERVAL = 2 # Number of DATA_INTERVAL between successive display updates (e.g. 2 => update display every second deta fetch)

# Note:
# The dimensions of the 2.7 in ePaper display are
# 264 x 176
# The dimensions of the Mini PiTFT display are
# 240 x 135

class Display(object):
    def __init__(self, imageWidth, imageHeight):
        self.imageWidth = imageWidth
        self.imageHeight = imageHeight

    # Draws the ISS current location and trajectory from array of positions
    def drawISS(self, positions):
        imageWhite = Image.new('1', (self.imageWidth, self.imageHeight), 255) # 1: clear the frame
        imageMap = Image.open('world_map_m.bmp').convert('L')
        imageWhite.paste(imageMap, (0,0))

        imageRed = Image.new('1', (self.imageWidth, self.imageHeight), 255) # 1: clear the frame
        issLogo = Image.open('iss.bmp').convert('L')
        drawred = ImageDraw.Draw(imageRed)

        for i,t in enumerate(positions):
            (lat,lon) = t

            # Map the lat, lon to our x/y coordinate system
            (x,y) = self.mapLatLongToXY(lat, lon)

            # last position in the positions array is the latest location
            # Every 15 minutes, we add a rectangular marker
            # and a small red circle to mark other locations

            if (i == len(positions) - 1):
                s = 10
                # drawred.rectangle((x-s,y-s,x+s,y+s), fill=0)
                imageRed.paste(issLogo, ((int)(x-s), (int)(y-s)))
            elif (((i+1) % (15 * 60 / DATA_INTERVAL)) == 0): # every 15 minutes (so 15 * 60s / DATA_INTERVAL = number of readings within 15 minutes)
                s = 2
                drawred.rectangle((x-s,y-s,x+s,y+s), fill=0)
            else:
                s = 1
                drawred.ellipse((x-s,y-s,x+s,y+s), outline=0)
                # drawred.point((x,y), fill=0)

        # Rotate image 180 degrees - Remove the # comments of the lines below to rotate the image and allow for alternate positioning/mounting of the Raspberry Pi 
        # imageRed = imageRed.transpose(Image.ROTATE_180)
        # imageWhite = imageWhite.transpose(Image.ROTATE_180)

        # return the rendered Red and White images
        return imageWhite, imageRed

    # Maps lat, long to x,y coordinates in 264x181 (the size of the world map)
    # (90 to -90 lat and -180 to 180 lon) map to 0-181 (y) and 0-264 (x) respectively
    # Simple algebra gives us the equations below
    # Recalculate as appropriate for map size and coordinates
    def mapLatLongToXY(self, lat, lon):
        x = (int)(0.733 * lon + 132)
        y = (int)(-1.006 * lat + 90.5)
        return x, y

# The main function
def main():
    # API to get ISS Current Location
    URL = 'http://api.open-notify.org/iss-now.json'

    # Initialize and clear the 2in7b (tri-color) display
    disp = st7789.ST7789(
        spi,
        cs=cs_pin,
        dc=dc_pin,
        rst=reset_pin,
        baudrate=BAUDRATE,
        width=135,
        height=240,
        x_offset=53,
        y_offset=40,
    )

    display = Display(disp.height, disp.width)

    # Store positions in list
    positions = []

    while(True):
        t0 = time()

        r = requests.get(url = URL)

        # extracting data in json format
        data = r.json()
        print(data)

        lat = float(data['iss_position']['latitude'])
        lon = float(data['iss_position']['longitude'])

        positions.append((lat, lon))
        print(positions)

        # Refresh the display on the first fetch and then on every DISPLAY_REFRESH_INTERVAL fetch
        if ((len(positions) >= 1) and ((len(positions)-1) % DISPLAY_REFRESH_INTERVAL)):
            disp.init()
            (imageWhite, imageRed) = display.drawISS(positions)
            # We're drawing the map in white and the ISS location and trajectory in red
            # Swap it around if you'd like the inverse color scheme
            disp.display(disp.getbuffer(imageWhite), disp.getbuffer(imageRed))
            sleep(2)
            disp.sleep()
       
        t1 = time()
        sleepTime = max(DATA_INTERVAL - (t1 - t0), 0)
        sleep(sleepTime) # sleep for 30 seconds minus duration of get request and display refresh



# gracefully exit without a big exception message if possible
def ctrl_c_handler(signal, frame):
    print('Goodbye!')
    # XXX : TODO
    #
    # To preserve the life of the ePaper display, it is best not to keep it powered up -
    # instead putting it to sleep when done displaying, or cutting off power to it altogether.
    #
    # dispconfig.module_exit() shuts off power to the module and calls GPIO.cleanup()
    # The latest disp library chooses to shut off power (call module_exit) even when calling disp.sleep()
    # disp.sleep() calls dispconfig.module_exit(), which in turns calls cleanup().
    # We can therefore end up in a situation calling GPIO.cleanup twice
    #
    # Need to cleanup Waveshare disp code to call GPIO.cleanup() only once
    # for now, calling dispconfig.module_init() to set up GPIO before calling module_exit to make sure
    # power to the ePaper display is cut off on exit
    # I have also modified dispconfig.py to initialize SPI handle in module_init() (vs. at the global scope)
    # because slepe/module_exit closes the SPI handle, which wasn't getting initialized in module_init
    # dispconfig.module_init()
    # dispconfig.module_exit()
    # print("Remeber to clear the display using cleardisplay.py if you plan to power down your Pi and store it, to prevent burn-in!")
    exit(0)

signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, ctrl_c_handler)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: It is usually customary to also include the output of the program, so we can know where the problem is occurring, if any. For example, you have

            disp.display(disp.getbuffer(imageWhite), disp.getbuffer(imageRed))

but I don't see a display method in the disp class. In Adafruit's example, I see that you should just set the display.image - you are already doing that in the beginning to an empty image. 

My guess is that you'll probably end up with a blank screen, and the program will also exit due to an exception because it cannot find disp.display (can be confirmed from output)

Comment: Precisely the problem. I'm very lost when it comes to Python.

Thanks for taking an interest in this!

Answer (score 0):

You can't do

disp.display(disp.getbuffer(imageWhite), disp.getbuffer(imageRed))

because your disp object has no method named "display"

Instead, you need to set the image in your disp object like so:

disp.image(imageRed, rotation)

In the original code, the display is divided into two sections - Red and Black. They get rendered by the ePaper separately, hence you needed two images.

In your display, your can construct a single image that has all colors, and then set that image to your disp.display

disp.display(newImage, rotation)

where newImage will be the image returned by the Display.drawISS method. You will need to modify the drawISS method (or create a new method, say called drawISS_TFT that returns a single image in RGB with both the map and the trajectory, in different colors (instead of the drawISS which draws out one image in Black and the other image in Red - just use a single image).

That should do the trick.

But first, to see your TFT display something, just replace

disp.display(disp.getbuffer(imageWhite), disp.getbuffer(imageRed))

with

disp.image(imageRed, rotation)
OR
disp.image(imageWhite, rotation)

If you see the ISS trajectory or World Map as appropriate, then you'll know you are on the right track before doing the other stuff.

-Sridhar